# How to remove day from datetime index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The idea behind this question is, that when I'm working with full datetime tags and data from different days, I sometimes want to compare how the hourly behavior compares.
But because the days are different, I can not directly plot two 1-hour data sets on top of each other.

My naive idea would be that I need to remove the day from the datetime index on both sets and then plot them on top of each other. What's the best way to do that?

Or, alternatively, what's the better approach to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be exactly it but should help you along, assuming `ts` is your timeseries:

```
hourly = ts.resample('H')
hourly.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([hourly.index.hour, hourly.index.normalize()])
hourly.unstack().plot()
```

If you don't care about the day AT ALL, just `hourly.index = hourly.index.hour` should work

Comment: what if I want compare compare how the minute behavior ?